# php extensions and shared hosting

Tags: php, shared-hosting, memcache

I'm on shared hosting and I'm trying to set up the memcached.so module to be used for php. Obviously I'm not able to put the .so file in /usr/lib64/php/modules so for my extension_dir value in my version of the php.ini (/home2/my_site/public_html/php.ini)I have:

```
extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules:/home2/my_site/apps/lib/php"
```

and at the bottom of the php.ini file I have

```
extension=memcache.so
```

However, the memcache module still isn't showing up in php_info(). Any suggestions on getting this working? Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question, but has the apache instance been restarted? (or PHP CGI if compiled like that)

If so, what are the errors in apache logs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to restart apache server to take its effect.

```
/etc/init.d/apachectl restart
```